# How to format this text in a fancy way

Tags: formatting

I have a set of couples, but when I write this code:

```
$k =  \{<\text{aaaabbb},\{10,17,40\}>,<\text{bbbbbbbbb},\{256\}>,
      <\text{fffff},\{367\}\}>,<\text{rrrr},\{459,16333\}\}>,
      <\text{sssadsadsa},\  {5555\}\}>$
```

the result is very bad. How can I format this text properly to have a nice alignment between the couples of the set.

Comment: please fix your example, so that people can run it and see the issue.

Comment: `<` and `>` are relations do not use them for angle brackets for that you want `\langle` and `\rangle`

Comment: you are setting this inline as part of a paragraph, what alignment do you mean in this case? If they are all on the same line what should align? Or do you want a multi-line display?

Comment: multi-line display because the set is too long to stay just in one line.

Comment: please (always) provide a complete small document for example we don't know how long your lines are, us-letter, a4, one-column, two-column,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer not to align the pairs to each other, but I provide also a solution for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pair}{\langle}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
k = \bigl\{ & \pair{\text{aaaabbb},\{10,17,40\}}, \pair{\text{bbbbbbbbb},\{256\}}, \\
            & \pair{\text{fffff},\{367\}}, \pair{\text{rrrr},\{459,16333\}}, 
              \pair{\text{sssadsadsa},\{5555\}} \bigr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
k = \bigl\{ 
  \!\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
  & \pair{\text{aaaabbb},\{10,17,40\}}, &\;& \pair{\text{bbbbbbbbb},\{256\}}, \\
  & \pair{\text{fffff},\{367\}},        &  & \pair{\text{rrrr},\{459,16333\}}, \\
  & \pair{\text{sssadsadsa},\{5555\}} \bigr\}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `<` and `>` for pairs. They should only be used for the relations “greater than” and “less than”.